# Move dropbox-client appindicator

Tags: 13.04, indicator, dropbox

I know, that it's possible, to re-arrange the ordering of the appindicators in the tray (this question has been asked a few times)

```
/usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile
```

and I know that it's possible to get the name of the different appindicators via this qdbus command:

```
qdbus --literal   com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar /com/canonical/Unity/Panel/Service                                  com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.Sync | sed -e 's/[^{]*{\(.*\)}\]/\1/' | sed -e 's/\[[^"]*/[/g' | sed -e 's/\[\(\(\("[^"]*"\|[^,"]*\), \)\{4\}\)[^]]*,\([^,]*\)\]/[\4, \1]/g' | sed -e 's/\[\([^,]*\, \)\("[^"]*",\)/[    \1\2 /g'  | sed -e 's/\[ *\(....,.\{24\}\) */[\1/g'  | sed -e 's/\], \[/]\n[/g'  | sort -n -k2
```

my problem is: the dropbox-client changes it's name of the appindicator (always "dropbox-client-" and a random(?) number).

Is it nevertheless possible to move the dropbox-appindicator (something like getting the number beforehand, and changing the file with a bash script?)

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try the wild card `*` instead of the number. I'm not saying this is the answer, but worth a try :)

Comment: nope, unfortunately not :( was thinking about this as well, but doesn't work

Comment: one thing I was able to find out, is that the random number is not random, but the process id, maybe that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, hope I can help anyone with the same problem (maybe a little bit "dirty", but it works!)

I created a bash file dropbox.sh:
    #!/bin/bash

```
dropbox start -i
sleep 1
b=`pidof dropbox`

c=`echo $b | cut -d' ' -f1`
c1=`echo $b | cut -d' ' -f2`

d="dropbox-client-$c=8"
d1="dropbox-client-$c1=8"
filename=~/.local/share/indicators/application/ordering-override.keyfile

count=0
while read LINE 
do
let count++
if [[ $LINE == *dropbox* ]];then
    c=$LINE
    e=$count
    e1=$(($e + 1))
    break
fi
done < $filename
sed -i "$e s/.*/$d/" $filename
sed -i "$e1 s/.*/$d1/" $filename
```

and replaced the startup command for dropbox with this bash-script, voilá!

edit: obviously you need two dropbox line in your ordering-override.keyfile since there are two possible pid's for dropbox after startup